# I can't get a value in my variable

Tags: php

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Panier</title>
       <?php
          $tot = 'test';
          $m1 = $_POST['montant1'];
       ?>
    </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Panier</h1>
    <table border=1>
    <form action="panier.php" method="POST">
        <tr><td>Produit</td><td>Quantite</td><td>Prix Unitaire</td><td>Action</td><tr>
        <tr><td>Produit 1</td><td><input type='text' name='montant1' value='2'></form></td><td>3.19</td><td><a href=>Supprimer</a></tr>
    </form> 
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

for some reason my variable $m1 can't get what's inside the input textfield 'montant1'

Comment: Where you are submitting the form?

Comment: There are two 'form' closing tags. And also no submit button? 
What is the name of this script? it should be "panier.php"

Answer (score 0):

If the file you have shown us isn't called "panier.php", try replacing

```
<form action="panier.php" method="POST">
```

with the below code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

which will cause the form to be submitted to the same URL that it came from.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - This is a valid attempt at an answer, and so shouldn't be flagged as "not an answer". If you don't like it (perhaps because it's useless) then the proper response is to down vote it, not flag it.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I didn't flag it, I didn't downvote it as the Answerer only had 6 points as it was. I just made a comment indicating that the answer was of not practical use what so ever.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Sorry, somebody flagged it. The flag review system didn't tell me who, so I guessed it was you based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have not added a submit button to your form, so there is no way of pushing the data forward! Add this after your text input tag (in the form).

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit your form">
```

Assuming that you are posting to the same page. Replace your PHP code with this:

```
 <?php
    if($_POST){
     $tot = 'test';
     $m1 = $_POST['montant1'];
    }
?>
```

This way you will handle the data only if it is there.

Also, it is recommended to put `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of the page name itself if you are posting on the same page. This way, you wouldn't have to handle code changes if you rename the file.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by formatting your code so it is readable. It helps you debug or rather not make silly mistakes.

There were a couple of obvious issues :-

You had 2 end form tags `</form>`

There was at least one missing `</td>`

You have no submit button.

The code to pick up what is submitted logically should go at the top of the script.

You need some way of deciding if this is the first execution of the script, as there will be no data passed on $_POST in that situation.

So try this instead, its basically your code with a little cleaning up.

```
<?php
    $tot = 'test';
    $m1 = isset($_POST['montant1']) 
                 ? $_POST['montant1'] 
                 : 'First run, the submit button has not been pressed yet';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Panier</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Panier</h1>
<?php
    echo 'You entered : ' . $m1;
?>

    <table border=1>

    <form action="panier.php" method="POST">
        <tr>
           <td>Produit</td>
           <td>Quantite</td>
           <td>Prix Unitaire</td>
           <td>Action</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Produit 1</td>
           <td><input type='text' name='montant1' value='2'></td>
           <td>3.19</td>
           <td><a href=>Supprimer</a></td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```